# I want to design E-mail client design

Tags: c++, linux

I want to design an email client and its environment in c++ languagewhich can provide similar facilities as gmail client has. Can somebody tell me what things i need to read and follow? or any help?

Comment: Notice that `gmail` is a web application, it is not a desktop email client (the mails are sent and received on google servers).

Answer (score 2):

Read a lot of books and web pages about [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smtp), [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP), [email clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_client), [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent). Consider using [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) and some libraries like [Vmime](http://www.vmime.org/)

Study the source code of several free software email clients like [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/), [evolution](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution), [kmail](http://userbase.kde.org/KMail)....

Be familiar with Linux, so read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

You might need several years of work.